# C# Try and Catch error message

Tags: c#, while-loop, try-catch

I recently started coding with c#, but I have encountered a problem that I have been trying to solve for a few hours now, so I thought I would give this a go. This is basically a simple program where the user can guess on a number between 1-20 and the computer will tell you if the number is too small or too big or if its the correct number.

Everything works fine except the try and catch part. I want the user to get an error message everytime they input a string instead of a number. I have tried different solutions but I can't work out what I have to put into the try block. As i said the program works fine when I don't use the try and catch, but when I use it the error message comes up every single time, so please help me and tell me what I have to write in the try part of the code.

this is the code:

```
using System;

namespace Uppgift_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random slumpat = new Random();
            int speltal = slumpat.Next(1,20); 

            bool spela = true; 
            while (spela)
            {
            Console.Write("\n\tGissa på ett tal mellan 1 och 20: ");
            int tal;
            Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tal);

            try
            {

            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fel, du får bara skriva in nummer");
            }


            if (tal < speltal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tDet inmatade talet " + tal + " är för litet, försök igen.");
            }

            else if (tal > speltal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tDet inmatade talet " + tal + " är för stort, försök igen.");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tGrattis, du gissade rätt!");
                spela = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) no exception will be thrown if given string cannot be parsed as integer number. This method will just return `false`. And you should check it:

```
Console.Write("\n\tGissa på ett tal mellan 1 och 20: ");
int tal;
if(!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out tal))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fel, du får bara skriva in nummer");
    continue;
}
```

When you use [`Int32.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) then exception will be thrown if string cannot be parsed:

```
Console.Write("\n\tGissa på ett tal mellan 1 och 20: ");
int tal;
try
{
   tal = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fel, du får bara skriva in nummer");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Should probably specify the exception in the catch `System.FormatException`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. This would definitely work, the only problem is that I have to use try and catch method for school. Can I somehow throw in an exception in the try and catch method?

Comment: @CNuts not only `FormatException` - there can be `OverflowException` as well

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Isn't it better to specify them then to let it catch any exception?

Comment: @mackanmorre The point of `TryParse` is that it *doesn't* throw an exception.  If you would rather catch an exception, just use `int.Parse`.

Comment: Ok I tried the Int32.Parse exactly as you wrote it. But the problem I get now is that my if else gets messed up.

Comment: @CNuts well.. in the perfect world it makes sense. But here chance that you will have exception from `Console.ReadLine()` is very small. So.. to simplify things and avoid duplication of error handling I used all-catching block

Comment: @mackanmorre what does that mean?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy further down in the code when we come to:

Comment: if (tal < speltal) i get the error message use of unassigned local variable tal

Comment: @mackanmorre then you probably missed `continue` keyword from my answer. It is there to break current iteration of `while` loop

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes my friend I did :) Everything works now, thank you soooo much!

Comment: @mackanmorre no problem. Consider to read [try-catch (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) for better understanding of exceptions handling